# Update data on database multiple uploaded file in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In this case if I want to update data multiple upload my old data not save in database

this is my controller

```
    //upload file
            $config['upload_path'] = './dokumen/pangkat_reguler/';
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $error = array();
            $files = array();

            foreach($_FILES as $field_name => $file)
            {
                if (! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
                {
                    $error[]=$this->upload->display_errors();
                }
                else 
                {
                    $files0 = $this->upload->data();
                    $files[] = $files0['file_name'];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Do you want to upload data on database?

Comment: @RamshaSaeed Thanks before, this case was solved